# PySpark: Time Stamp is changed when exported to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pyspark

I am new to PySpark. I have a table in SQL Server `df` as follows:

```
DeviceID       TimeStamp            A      B     C
 00234       11-03-2014 05:55      5.6    2.3   3.3
 00235       11-03-2014 05:33      2.8    0.9   4.2
 00236       11-03-2014 06:15      3.5    0.1   1.3
 00234       11-03-2014 07:23      2.5    0.2   3.9
 00236       11-03-2014 07:33      2.5    4.5   2.9
```

Objective / What I want:
To find the `max` values of each `DeviceID` and their corresponding `TimeStamp`. Besides, I also need to have the current time stamp so that on daily basis I should know when the `max` value did occur for each `DeviceID`.

So the resultant `df_final` should be like

```
DeviceID    Max_Value       TimeStamp           Curr_TimeStamp
00234          5.6        11-03-2014 05:55     11-03-2014 23:54
00236          4.5        11-03-2014 07:33     11-03-2014 23:54
```

To achieve the above `df_final`, I have used `Window` function. Below is my code snippets.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

##Initialize Spark Session##
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/path/to/sqljdbc-6.4.jar").getOrCreate()
##Fetch data from SQL Server table df ##
df = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(url="SQL Server details",properties = 
{ "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
},dbtable="df").load()

##Create a Temp View for further processing##
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_temp")

##Get only a days data##
df_view = spark.sql("select * from df_temp where TimeStamp between date_add(current_date(),-1) and current_date()")

#Finally creating the dataframe df_final as required##
w = Window.partitionBy('DeviceImei')
df_final = df_view.select('DeviceImei','DeviceTimeStamp',F.greatest('IL1','IL2','IL3').alias('max_value'))
df_final = df_final.withColumn('Max-TimeStamp',F.max('max_value').over(w)).where(F.col('max_value') == F.col('Max-TimeStamp')).drop('Max-TimeStamp').withColumn('TimeStamp',F.current_timestamp())
```

So far so good!! However, strange thing happens when I export this to another SQL Server table.

```
df_final.write.jdbc(url="SQL Server details", table="MaxLoad", mode="append", properties={ "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" })
```

What I am getting as follows:

```
DeviceID    Max_Value         TimeStamp         Curr_TimeStamp
00234          5.6        10-03-2014 10:55     11-03-2014 23:54
00236          4.5        10-03-2014 12:33     11-03-2014 23:54
```

As you can see the `TimeStamp` values have been changed!!

Why such thing is happening? Am I missing any thing in the code? I have checked the system time stamp at both Spark and SQL server machine and they are perfect.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S: Spark 2.4.1 is running on CentOS 7 and I am using SQL Server 2014 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I bet your Spark Cluster and MS SQL Server are located in different time-zones.  I have experienced this and the solution would be to use UTC TZ by setting conf `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Etc/UTC")`.  By setting this conf your time-stamps should be giving you what you expect when you persist now to MS SQL Server.

Disclaimer: ***I think setting the Spark TZ conf to UTC will fix your problem however your time-stamp format might be causing issues too ... the recommended java format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss***

Here is an example of one of your time-stamps behaving differently under different time-zones

```py
spark.version
'2.4.3'

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# you can check Spark Cluster TZ like this
spark.conf.get("spark.sql.session.timeZone")
"will list your server tz here"

# change to UTC to fix problem / preserve event time source data timestamp
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Etc/UTC")

# let's take one of your timestamp and convert to unix for testing
ut = spark.createDataFrame([('11-03-2014 05:55',)], ['ut'])
ut.select(unix_timestamp('ut', 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm').alias('ut')).show()

+----------+
|        ut|
+----------+
|1414994100|
+----------+

# let's test the output with a system set at LA TZ to see the timestamp changes
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "America/Los_Angeles")

la_time = spark.createDataFrame([(1414994100,)], ['la_tz'])
la_time.select(from_unixtime('la_tz').alias('la_tz')).show() # different ts as source

+-------------------+
|              la_tz|
+-------------------+
|2014-11-02 21:55:00|
+-------------------+

# set TZ back to UTC to confirm timestamp has preserved source data event time
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Etc/UTC")

utc = spark.createDataFrame([(1414994100,)], ['utc_tz'])
utc.select(from_unixtime('utc_tz').alias('utc_tz')).show() # same ts as source

+-------------------+
|             utc_tz|
+-------------------+
|2014-11-03 05:55:00|
+-------------------+

# reset TZ conf if you want
spark.conf.unset("spark.sql.session.timeZone")

# if you want to change your timestamp format
ts = spark.createDataFrame([('11-03-2014 05:55',)], ['ts'])
ts.select(to_timestamp('ts', 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm').alias('ts')).show()

+-------------------+
|                 ts|
+-------------------+
|2014-11-03 05:55:00|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks I will see this.

Comment: Can you please tell me whether I can use the following `spark.sql` syntax in this case to get rid out of Time Format problem? `spark.sql("select * from df_temp where DeviceTimeStamp between date_add(from_unixtime(current_date()),-1) and from_unixtime(current_date())")`

Comment: added how you can in the solution, but your main question was about the different timestamps when writing to mysql ... did you check this against the solution provided?

Comment: I just added the line `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Etc/UTC")` and it did work. My source data timestamp is in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format only.

Comment: thanks....by the way `spark.sql("select * from df_temp where DeviceTimeStamp between date_add(from_unixtime(current_date()),-1) and from_unixtime(current_date())")` will this command work?

Comment: i tried it and it is subtracting a day so maybe not what you are looking for.